# get filenames inside list of subdirectories using python

Tags: python, list

i have folder which have many sub-folders and each sub-folders have files. 
i want to create a list with all the filenames from all sub-folders.

Problem is all the filenames are not appended to list.

```
listdir = os.listdir()#getting all the subfoldersname in list.

for i in listdir:  ### for loop to append filename in filename list.
    filename=[]
    filename.append(os.listdir(i))

#output [['3.txt']]
```

Comment: You are creating a new `filename` array in every loop. That should probably be outside the loop.

Comment: yeah, i tried creating list outside of loop and append in every iteration.

Comment: Two points. 1. `os.listdir` is not recursive. use `os.walk` instead. 2.`filename` re-assigned to empty list in each iteration. So you will get only the last iteration value.

Comment: @AbdulNiyasPM thank you